# É possível recompilar uma APK para Android para mudar somente o nome e ícone?

Tags: android-studio, apk

Bom pessoal, eu comprei um site completo + APP para Android, enviei para eles compilarem para Android o PNG para o Ícone e o Título, mas infelizmente não ficou bom e gostaria de mudar. Pedi suporte a eles para recompilar, mas que me cobraram 87 dólares e no momento não posso, gostaria de saber se é possível recompilar eu mesmo, sou estudante na área.

Comment: O problema é assinar o APK, e não compilar. Mas nesse preço aí dá pra pagar a licença do Google, usar as ferramentas gratuitas e ainda sobra troco.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer algumas alterações no APK sim, mas isso depende de como ele foi gerado e assinado. O formato APK nada mais é do que um arquivo ZIP, quando visto de forma simplória.

Você poderia, em alguns casos, alterar os ícones manualmente usando um aplicativo como o 7-Zip ou WinRAR. Entretanto, acredito que a forma mais simples de fazê-lo seria usando o [APK Icon Editor](http://kefir500.github.io/apk-icon-editor/).

Basta carregar a APK no aplicativo e no menu Ícone utilizar as opções de substituição. O programa possui dois modos de operação, o **ZIP** e o **APK Tool**. O primeiro faz uma substituição simples dos arquivos de ícone (deve solucionar o seu problema); o segundo oferece recursos mais avançados, em maioria ligados à engenharia reversa. Você pode seleciona-los nas configurações do programa.

EDIT: Outra opção é utilizar o programa APK Manager. [Este tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701) do Fórum XDA Developers detalha o procedimento.

Comment: O ponto mais importante, e que faltou na resposta, é que após qualquer alteração, precisa assinar de novo depois, com uma chave válida de desenvolvedor (hoje custa 25 dólares, e a ferramenta é gratuita. Ainda é muito mais barato do que os 87 dólares que querem cobrar).